# Map v2 convert distance to pixels

Tags: android

I have been searching but I couldn't find it. I am using google map v2. Is there any way I can convert distance ( meters) to pixels on my screen? I need the pixels equivalent of the distance. I have the distance and I have the zoom level.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify are you converting distance of two points? Or do you want to know how many miles your screen is showing?

Comment: The distance is between 2 points. However I know the distance only not the points. Actually, I have a circle (so I know the center point and the radius. I want to know how many pixels this radius is equal to.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you have a MapFragment on your screen showing a map. You know the distance in meters between 2 points on the map that are shown on the screen and you want to calculate the distance between those two points in pixels. If you know the LatLng location of the two points, you can use the Projection class like this:

```
Point point1 = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(latLng1);
Point point2 = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(latLng2);
```

and then you just need to use the distance mathematic formula: [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I don't know the latlng of 2 points. I just know distance in meters and one point. For example,imagine a circle with center  point and radius. I would like to know how many pixels is this radius equal to.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer , for anyone who's feeling lazy :) here is the equation Math.sqrt((Math.pow(point2.x - point1.x, 2) + Math.pow(point2.y - point1.y, 2)));